# Load external js file in another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this file include in my html and I want to call it from another javascript.
Please suggest me how should I do it?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js">/*
  old:123
  new: 456*/
</script>
```

I want to include it in my js file, not in the html.

Comment: There is nothing to call...?

Comment: You want to do what? Also.. that way of using JavaScript blocks is invalid and won't work/

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839698/jquery-getscript-alternative-in-native-javascript

Comment: script block is in the html's head.. not in the js file. I want to do the same using another js file.

Comment: You can use server side languages to generate dynamic js scripts so calling it with a parameter will generate something else. Thats all i can offer

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you want to include a JS file in a JS you can use [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) for that

```
$.getScript('another_file.js', function() {
    //script is loaded and executed put your dependent JS here
});
```

And if you cannot use jQuery

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = '/path/to/imported/script';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4634669/1893629)

For more information about the current CSP3 spec from W3 look [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#csp-header).

Comment: How to pass the parameters?  old:123
  new: 456

Comment: for what  you have to pass the parameter??

Comment: @Gaurav check out this article http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html

Comment: to the js like the linkedIn js api

Comment: @Gaurav I would add those LinkedIn variables in the script then if you are setting them

Comment: Thank you @doitlikejustin that worked excellent for my project!

Comment: the second one worked for me