# eval() doesn't execute external (src=…) scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm using eval() to execute all `<script>` tags after total rewrite of a div.

```js
$("#content").find("script").each(function(){
    eval($(this).text());
});
```

It works well for inline-scripts, but has no effect on scripts like:

```js
<script src="/path/to/externalScript.js"></script>
```

How come? Can I "force" the browser to load and execute also the external scripts?

Comment: You arent suppose to use Eval anymore..  I got reamed out by the internet years ago when trying to use it.  Opens you up for injection.

Comment: Yes I know, but it's the the only solution that i Know. I try to load a script after ajax response

Comment: What does `$(this).text()` contain? Likely nothing as the `script` element doesn't have text content. You'd want to perform an Ajax request for the script, read its text content, and call `eval` on that.

Comment: @Whymarrh, not full duplicate because of [tag:jquery]

Comment: @Qwertiy sorry, jQuery here makes very little difference. The question is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the very real issues with using [`eval`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94017/what-are-the-security-issues-with-eval-in-javascript), you are trying to `eval` the `.text` inside those script tags, which is essentially nothing.

When a `<script>` tag loads, it links in the external file as a resource to your page and executes the script. It does not render anything directly to the dom.

Thus you `$(this).text()` will return ''.

If you want to reload the external scripts, you will either need to force a page refresh, or potentially change the way you are pulling in those scripts: ex. [jQuery.getScript alternative in native JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839698/jquery-getscript-alternative-in-native-javascript)

Answer (score -2):

```js
$("body").css("background", "silver");

$("button").click(function () {
  $("script[src^='data:']").each(function () {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = this.src;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="data:text/javascript,document.body.style.background='red'"></script>
<button>Go</button>
```

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work

Comment: @bildstein, as you see, it does.