# Chrome App using Apps Script API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-chrome-app

Ran into another road block today, on my path of writing a desktop chrome app for logging users project time.

What i am trying to do (and failing) is use the Apps Script API to access a google sheet that retains the information (project numbers) that i want to populate a drop down in my Chrome App UI.

**Update:**
I have reworded this as to get to the point and be a little clear on what my issue is.

What i cant seem to achieve is calling the Apps script function from my chrome app. I have read this [Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/js#step_2_set_up_the_sample) but still cant seem to make the coloration. for some reasons i keep getting the "Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined" in my  console.

What i have managed to do is have both the Apps Script and the Chrome App under the same project name in the Developers Console. not sure if its needed but thought it might help with only 1 Oauth2 request.

Is there something my thick head is missing?

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

This is my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "TimeSheet",
  "description": "Small and easy desktop app for entering time spent on project files",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "app.window.alwaysOnTop"
    ],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "clientid.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
      
      ]
  },
  "key": "very long string"
}
```

This is the bit of Oauth2 code running in my main.js

```
//This code confirms Oauth2 for access to google drive and related files

window.onload = function(){
  
  document.querySelector("#Oauth2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({"interactive": true}, function(token){
      console.log(token);
      
    });
  });

};

// ID of the script to call. Acquire this from the Apps Script editor,
// under Publish > Deploy as API executable.
var scriptId = "blah";
// Create execution request.
var request = {
    'function': 'getProjectNumbers',
};

// Make the request.
var op = gapi.client.request({
    'root': 'https://script.googleapis.com',
    'path': 'v1/scripts/' + scriptId + ':run',
    'method': 'POST',
    'body': request
});
// Log the results of the request.
op.execute(function(resp) {
  if (resp.error && resp.error.status) {
    // The API encountered a problem before the script started executing.
    console.log('Error calling API: ' + JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2));
  } else if (resp.error) {
    // The API executed, but the script returned an error.
    var error = resp.error.details[0];
    console.log('Script error! Message: ' + error.errorMessage);
    if (error.scriptStackTraceElements) {
      // There may not be a stacktrace if the script didn't start executing.
      console.log('Script error stacktrace:');
      for (var i = 0; i < error.scriptStackTraceElements.length; i++) {
        var trace = error.scriptStackTraceElements[i];
        console.log('\t' + trace.function + ':' + trace.lineNumber);
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Here, the function returns an array of strings.
    var projectNumbers = resp.response.result;
    console.log('Project numbers in spreadsheet:');
    projectNumbers.forEach(function(name){
      console.log(name);
    });
  }
});
```

And this is the apps script code:

```
var projectDatabaseKey = 'blah'; //Project Database Sheet spreadsheet key
var pprojectDatabaseSheet = 'Project Database'; //Project Database  Sheet spreadsheet sheet

//Function to revieve data of project numbers for drop down list
function getProjectNumbers() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
   .openById(projectDatabaseKey).getSheetByName(projectDatabaseSheet)
   .getRange("A2:A" + (SpreadsheetApp.openById(projectDatabaseKey).getSheetByName(projectDatabaseSheet).getLastRow()))
   .getValues();
}
```

I am just really unsure how to use the Oauth2 token and how to apply it to the apps script.

**UPDATE**

Ok i have tried to call an apps script in a different manor, What i am trying today is using the gapi-chrome-apps.js library to do the oauth2 work.

Now my problem is i get this error, that could be a range of things i am guessing:

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/blahblah:run 404 ()
>
> gapi.client.request @ VM80 gapi-chrome-apps.js:105
>
> getSheetsList @ gapiCallback.js:17
>
> (anonymous function) @ gapiCallback.js:49
>
> callbackWrapper @ VM80 gapi-chrome-apps.js:68
>
> target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19
>
> safeCallbackApply @ extensions::sendRequest:21
>
> handleResponse @ extensions::sendRequest:72

And this Error, that comes from the gapi-chrome-apps.js script:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0

Really not sure what is causing this, here is my updated code:

```
//get listof sheets in spreadsheet
function getSheetsList(){
  var scriptId = "blahblah";
  // Initialize parameters for function call.
  var sheetId = "blahblah";
  // Create execution request.
  var requests = {
      'function': 'getSheetNames',
      'parameters': [sheetId],
      'devMode': true   // Optional.
  };
  // Make the request.
  gapi.client.request({
      'root': 'https://script.googleapis.com',
      'path': 'v1/scripts/' + scriptId + ':run',
      'method': 'POST',
      'body': requests,
      'callback': printSheetsList
  });
}
// Log the results of the request.
function printSheetsList(resp) {
  if (resp.error && resp.error.status) {
    // The API encountered a problem before the script started executing.
    console.log('Error calling API: ' + JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2));
  } else if (resp.error) {
    // The API executed, but the script returned an error.
    var error = resp.error.details[0];
    console.log('Script error! Message: ' + error.errorMessage);
  } else {
    // Here, the function returns an array of strings.
    var sheetNames = resp.response.result;
    console.log('Sheet names in spreadsheet:');
    sheetNames.forEach(function(name){
    console.log(name);
    });
  }
}
//Prompts the user for authorization and then proceeds to 
function authorize(params, callback) {
  gapi.auth.authorize(params, function(accessToken) {
    if (!accessToken) {
      console.log("Error getting authorization");
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  });
}
function gapiIsLoaded() {
  var params = { 'immediate': true };
  if (!(chrome && chrome.app && chrome.app.runtime)) {
    params.scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
    params.client_id = "blahblah";
    gapi.auth.init(authorize.bind(null, params, getSheetsList));
  } else {
    authorize(params, getSheetsList);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in particular, show us your attempt at calling the apps script execution API and where it fails.

Comment: I have added in the request i am making the apps script but not sure how to make the connection with the Oauth2, i also get "Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined" i am guessing that is cause of me missing a step potentially with the connection between the Oauth2 and the Apps Script. I am a pretty big noob at these chrome apps. alot more steps than i am used to with apps script.

Comment: I have tried a few different things and it looks like my issue is with the .gapi and not able to load the client library api due to the security policy. Will have to try a work around.

Comment: i dont see where you are adding the access token. have you followed the examples for calling execution api? why not using the client libraries? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api#general_procedure

Comment: That seems to be one of my issues atm. Its says the client library violates the security policy due to 'self'. I have found a work around on the chome dev site. Will give that ago today. This is all new territory for me so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try loading the library from a webpage and see what js file it finally downloads. you need to include that file locally in the extension or make the correct POST call like yours but with the access token. look at other google apis that make authebticated calls director with post/get and imitate the auth part (bearer etc)

Comment: Think i am going to put this one in the to hard basket, just cant seem to find a way. doesn't seem like anyone has tried to use the apps script api in chrome apps. just can not figue out how to pass the `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` into the script request. :(

Comment: try making the call work from the oauth2 playground, then see how it builds the POST request (look for the "bearer" part) https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ or use the client libraries to make a "regular" webapp, and use the chrome network inspector to see how it makes the POST.

Comment: Ok got the api working on the Oauth Playground, i had to add the scope of the GAS sheet i was calling the information from. i have updated the error i am getting in the post.

Answer (score 2):

Using traditional GAPI will not work, since it dynamically loads more external scripts and Apps [are not allowed to do that](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy).

One possible solution is to run GAPI code in a [sandboxed page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox), which can overcome the remote code restriction. This, however, is cumbersome as you'll need to pass data back and forth using `postMessage`.

Another way is to try and use Google-provided library [gapi-chrome-apps.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/libraries/gapi-chrome-apps-lib), that works in Chrome apps (and uses `chrome.identity` to manage OAuth) - but please note this comment:

> This library is likely not suitable for use without additional modifications.

Comment: Hi Xan's, i have been trying to use the gapi-chrome-apps.js but you are totally correct about the additional modification required. It still requires several callback functions but makes more sense because it requires the scopes and client id Something i think has to be part of the request process. I am going to try several options with this over the weekend and hopefully make some ground. For some reason i thought because they are all google services they would work easily together. What a fool i was lol

Comment: GAPI was designed to dynamically load remote code. Apps were designed to severely limit external dependencies. You can see where this trainwreck is going.

Comment: Is there a way to just use the identity api do you think?. This works a treat for  getting the oauth2 for the app its self but i have to idea at whats involved to use it for a function like passing the apps script oauth2. On the plus side of all this head banging is i am learning more :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your post, you are simply not defining `gapi`.  You can load it like this

```
jQuery.getScript( "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js", onApiLoad );
```

where `onApiLoad` is the function you would like to call when the `gapi` is loaded.

For your code, I would wrap the following code in a function like this:

```
function onApiLoad() {
    // Make the request.
    var op = gapi.client.request({
        'root': 'https://script.googleapis.com',
        'path': 'v1/scripts/' + scriptId + ':run',
        'method': 'POST',
        'body': request
    });
    // Log the results of the request.
    op.execute(function(resp) {
      if (resp.error && resp.error.status) {
        // The API encountered a problem before the script started executing.
        console.log('Error calling API: ' + JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2));
      } else if (resp.error) {
        // The API executed, but the script returned an error.
        var error = resp.error.details[0];
        console.log('Script error! Message: ' + error.errorMessage);
        if (error.scriptStackTraceElements) {
          // There may not be a stacktrace if the script didn't start executing.
          console.log('Script error stacktrace:');
          for (var i = 0; i < error.scriptStackTraceElements.length; i++) {
            var trace = error.scriptStackTraceElements[i];
            console.log('\t' + trace.function + ':' + trace.lineNumber);
          }
        }
      } else {
        // Here, the function returns an array of strings.
        var projectNumbers = resp.response.result;
        console.log('Project numbers in spreadsheet:');
        projectNumbers.forEach(function(name){
          console.log(name);
        });
      }
    });

}
```

### Edit: no jQuery, only pure JS

Thanks to [the second answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839698/jquery-getscript-alternative-in-native-javascript), the below code is a pure JS implementation of $.getScript().  It includes a callback, so the code snippet below should work, assuming you wrap your code in a function as described above.

```
function getScript(source, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    var prior = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    script.async = 1;
    prior.parentNode.insertBefore(script, prior);

    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function( _, isAbort ) {
        if(isAbort || !script.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test(script.readyState) ) {
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
            script = undefined;

            if(!isAbort) { if(callback) callback(); }
        }
    };

    script.src = source;
}


getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/api.js", onApiLoad);
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for you answer, only problem i seem to have now is loading jQuery, "jQuery is not defined" from what i gather loading it via the manifest  "content_scripts" is not allowed in packaged apps :(

Comment: @David Added solution using pure JS, I hope it helps solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for helping Eric, This definitely is shining a glimmer of hope. The only issue is CSP wont allow an external source. `main.js:39 Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:"` I found on github a .js file for the gapi to save as a local copy but when referancing that i get this: `gapiIsLoaded callback function must be defined prior to loading gapi-chrome-apps.js` that comes from the gapi local file. trying to work my google magic atm.

Comment: I copied the api and loaded the api as a local script `getScript("api.js?onload=handleClientLoad", onApiLoad);` now i get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined` from the `var op = gapi.client.request({` line. its seems to be one brick wall after the next. i also tried putting the page in sandbox and that gave me this same error so at least its getting to this far in the code, just need it to execute the full client request.

Comment: Downvote: Chrome Apps [are not allowed to load external scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy), so all of this is not useful.

Comment: I can use Erics to get as far as the request when i reference a local gapi file. But then i get the error in my comment above, what i think derives from not enough information pasted to make the client request. So i need to include the client id and the scopes i think. I wish there was a easy way of just using the identity api to do the request rather than all the fluff with the gapi.client.request :( and i thought it would only take a day to make this app lol

Comment: @David have you seen [this page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/).  I'll admit, I have not written a Chrome App before, so I may be way off base, but it might give you guidance on how to configure your request.